# WCF JSON HTTP 400 bad request

Tags: c#, json, wcf, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying a WCF Web service with JSON post method:

**Service1.svc**

```
  [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(
       RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {


        public string GetData(string id)
        {
           // return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
            return "you entered " + id;
        }
```

**IService1.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
     [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "data/{id}")]
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(string id);
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <!--<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>-->
    <compilation/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then I hosted .svc on IIS and tested JSON with below on IE
http://localhost/WCFService/Service1.svc/data/10

But getting

> http 400 bad request

Here the WCF Test Client, calling service method:
[image]
I found a solution on Stackoverlow.
[C# 4.0 WCF REST JSON - HTTP GET CODE 400 Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428010/c-sharp-4-0-wcf-rest-json-http-get-code-400-bad-request)

tried with below web.config file: but still its not working (http 400 bad request)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>  
 </configuration>
```

Comment: a `REST` service is exposed only via `WebHttpBinding` and doesn't expose any metadata.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of searching I found a solution at [configuring WCF with <services> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731403/configuring-wcf-with-services-tag)

Here is the web.config file, that is working:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <!--<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>-->
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceApp.Service1">
        <endpoint address="../Service1.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceApp.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehaviour">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I believe below part did the trick:

> **WcfServiveApp** is my namespace and **Service1** is class and **IService1** is
>   interface.

```
<services>
  <service name="WcfServiceApp.Service1">
    <endpoint address="../Service1.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceApp.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour"/>
  </service>
</services>
```